# styling a js made table

Tags: javascript, css

I'm not able to style my js function.
The style isn't applied on the rows:

```
function mulTable(){
        window.alert("hello!");
        document.write("<table style='border-width:2px;border-color: blue; border-style: solid;'>");
        var trs=parseInt(window.prompt("How many rows:",""));
        var tds=parseInt(window.prompt("How many cols:",""));
        var i=1, j=1;
        while(trs>=i){
        document.write("<tr style='border-width:2px; border-style: solid;'>");
        while(tds>=j){
           document.write("<td style='width:30px;background-color:yellow;text-align:center;'>"+i*j+"</td>");

           j++;
        }
        j=1;
        document.write("</tr>");
        i++;
        }
            document.write("</table>");
        }
```

What might be the problem?
Thanks!!!!

Comment: your code seems to be working. it asks for number of rows and cols, and then render a table with a blue border and yellow background on every cell

Comment: `document.write` probably isn't the way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i'm really new to js, started learning it only this week, so perhaps not sure how to build tables correctly or in the best way possible....back to my question - i wanted the output to be a table with blue cols and rows lines, yellow background, and it looked strange.then  i've changed only the tr and table style and it worked :)